# screen label color varied between iphone simulator and device?

Tags: iphone, ios

In my application, I set `Red(34)`,`Green(7)`,`Blue(107)` values for my UILabel. When I run in iPhone simulator it shows exact color what I need. But when I run this in iPhone device it shows some color variation compared to iPhone simulator. But when I take screenshot from iPhone device it shows exact color. I am really confused. I can't get my color varied screen shot.

So can anyone test this with your sample application(using label) , and provide me a your comments and feedback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this happens, So you can not rely only by checking and getting approved by showing in Simulator. You need to check it live in iPhone.

What you can do is add some extra values and check again in iPhone

Red +(10-15),
Green +20,
Blue +15

This will give color near to what you want in iPhone.

Comment: Try with Red(34+12),Green(7+20),Blue(107+15). And let me know, is your desired result ?

Comment: No anoop it doesn't meet my requirements. Thanks for your effort. You try this with UILabel right, So plz take screen shot from your device. Then you will see the difference between your device image and screen shot image. I have written a lots of app but didn't meet this type of case.  thx

Comment: Did you check what i said? may i know your comments ... plz

Comment: Currently I dont have mac. Am i PC... i can not check now... but That color diferences is known, as we do as suggested by adding some extra.

Comment: Will this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039641/ios-color-on-xcode-simulator-is-different-from-the-color-on-device

Comment: And this is a good question, so +1 for you, now you can vote up :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the precise physical capabilities of the display of an iPhone and the Mac greatly differ. This is not a programming/software error, you can't really do anything about it.

Comment: My app layout designed by client , so i dont have rights to change its design and colors ...I need to produce 100% what they need. Thats why i need help?

Comment: @MathanKumar See, you **can't** do anything. That's all. Even different iPhones' screens differ. That's how it works.