# Xcode: Storyboard and simulator image are different colors

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have an image on a storyboard view, and it looks fine, but when I run it in the simulator, it changes colors and is darker. Does anyone else have this problem?

I am new to the site, so it wont let me post images, https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTr4L.jpg

Thank you!

Comment: What does it look like on the device?

Comment: Darker, same as simulator

Comment: Like this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039641/ios-color-on-xcode-simulator-is-different-from-the-color-on-device

Comment: I dont think so, it doesnt look different on everything, it just looks different on the sim and the device from the storyboard preview

Answer (score 0):

On simulator menu bar from tab **Debug** uncheck all options and you can **reset** the **content and settings** of simulator. May it can change the color schema of simulator.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, the images are still darker on the simulator and device than in the storyboard.

Comment: Can you do one thing, upload that image to any where like Facebook or twitter & then view it into device. Is it still look the same or different. then we can conclude something where actually problem is.

Comment: have you look imgur in device, or open imgur into your simulator safari.