# Xcode 6: Navigation bar doesn't show real color

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I try to change color of navigation bar but although I set the color as #33A99B, the color is shown as #339B89 in the simulator.

How can I set real color?

Comment: Is `translucent == NO` and `opaque == YES` set?

Comment: Yes, I tried to this way, but nothing changed.

Comment: Maybe a screenshot would help.

Comment: How do you know which color is shown in the simulator?

Comment: Thank you @SebastianDressler I added two screenshot / iOS simulator: http://imgur.com/0vGvVwF - Configuration: http://imgur.com/7waGJRq

Comment: @LastMove I used a color picker app and you can see the inconsistency between image layer and background -> imgur.com/0vGvVwF

Comment: Maybe this related question helps: [iOS - color on xcode simulator is different from the color on device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039641/ios-color-on-xcode-simulator-is-different-from-the-color-on-device)?

Answer (score 0):

I tried with what you mentioned and it was working fine.

[image]

Below is how and where i set color.

[image]

You may be doing something wrong. Please check it and revert.