# iOS: Colors defined in Interface Builder different from colors in Web View

Tags: ios, uiview, colors, uiwebview

We're building an iOS app which partly makes use of `UIWebView`s to render some UI elements. I noticed, that colors which are defined on the Storyboard are rendered differently than colors with the **same** values in the Web View. The following screenshot shows three example colors on the storyboard and in the emulator: `#00C2F0`, `#00843C` and `#FF008F`.

[image: shifted colors Interface Builder and Emulator]

The left squares show each color rendered as CSS `background-color` within a `UIWebView`, the right square shows the color assigned as background to a `UIView` directly through Interface Builder.

When I take a screenshot and measure the color values in Photoshop, the color shown within the `UIWebView` is exactly as defined (i.e. exactly matching the hex color values given above), whereas the color shown through the `UIView` is shifted.

I've read several posts about "wrong" colors on iOS, which explain this "issue" due to color management with the goal to have a consistent visual appearance on all devices (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578759/wrong-color-in-interface-builder) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039641/ios-color-on-xcode-simulator-is-different-from-the-color-on-device)). While this sounds totally reasonable, it does not explain the inconsistent rendering through different controls.

Is there anything I can do to achieve matching colors between iOS native views and colors rendered within a `UIWebView`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally solved my issue: The reason was not `UIWebView`-specific as I had originally assumed, but caused by the fact, that the colors assigned through Interface Builder were in sRGB color space. Changing to "Generic RGB" **and then** re-assigning the hex color values solved my issue.

[image: color picker color space]

Very helpful was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28037691/hex-colors-in-ios-are-not-accurate) question and answer (I feel the duplicate flag is unjustified).

Comment: For me I had two UIViewControllers in a Storyboard where the background color had the same code, but looked different visually.  I had investigated opacity and alpha...and got stuck.  This resolved it.  I'm not sure how they got set differently in the first place.

Comment: I think Device RGB works best. Apps like color picker then retrieve the value as defined in xcode storyboard.

Comment: Generic RGB did *not* work for me. However, Device RGB *did* work to match colors between my Storyboard and Web View.