# Display SRGB value as a background colour to a view

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor, nscolor

I get an output that says `ExtendedSRGB`. I have given the output that I got below:

I need to display the `SRGB` colour in a `UIView`, so it appears something like:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = SRGB VALUES
```

But, unlike `RGB` values `SRGB` values range from `0..1`. Therefore, how can I display colour.

> [
>   (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelRGB; sRGB IEC61966-2.1)] (
>   0.745098 0.745098 1 1 )

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below :

```
let sRGB = CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB)!
let cgRequiredColor = CGColor(colorSpace: sRGB, components: [0.745098, 0.745098, 1, 1])!
let requiredColor = UIColor(cgColor: cgRequiredColor)
self.view.backgroundColor = requiredColor
```

As per sRGV values, output is :

[image]

For more stuff, Refer to links:

https://codexample.org/questions/779247/how-do-i-compare-2-uicolor-objects-which-are-kcgcolorspacemodelrgb-and-uiextendedsrgbcolorspace-instances-in-logs.c
[iOS - color on xcode simulator is different from the color on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039641/ios-color-on-xcode-simulator-is-different-from-the-color-on-device)
[hex colors in iOS are not accurate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28037691/hex-colors-in-ios-are-not-accurate)

Hope will be helping!

Comment: From my output how can I extract the values `[0.745098, 0.745098, 1, 1]` ?