# xCode simulator is a different colour?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I have no idea why, but the colours seem to be changing from the XIB/Storyboard to the device/simulation.

See below for a clear example of what's happening *(the red has been added in Photoshop to hide the company name)*

[image]

On the left is the xCode Storyboard, on the right is the simulator.
As you can see, the shade of blue is dramatically changed!

Any idea as to why, and how I can fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS - color on xcode simulator is different from the color on device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039641/ios-color-on-xcode-simulator-is-different-from-the-color-on-device)