# Core Graphics gives different color

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I have strange result with Core Graphics when draw rectangle with stroke color.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGFloat inset = 0.5 / [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, inset);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorFromHex:@"#ff9b95"].CGColor);
    CGContextStrokeRect(context, CGRectMake(BORDER_SIZE + inset, 0, CGRectGetWidth(rect) - 2 * BORDER_SIZE - 2 * inset, CGRectGetHeight(rect)));

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Here I have red color with hex value `#ff9b95`. But when I save screenshot from simulator and check color value in Photoshop, I see `#ff685f` and it looks visually lighter then original color. It looks like alpha value is in game, but I don't touch it.

Comment: This is a known occurrence. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039641/ios-color-on-xcode-simulator-is-different-from-the-color-on-device

Comment: In provided link I see color space sRGB. I use it too.