# "Display P3" screenshots from iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, screenshot, color-profile

Is there a way to get "Display P3" screenshots from the simulator? The difference in the greens is terrible! But having to do 55 screenshots from the device instead is much more work.

I'm on a MacBook Pro with Touch Bar that should technically be able to display P3 colors.

[image]

Comment: A shot in the dark: have you tried changing your monitor profile to P3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Unfortunately, the QuartzCore software renderer only supports sRGB.  There is no way to get extended range sRGB or P3 out of that render pipeline in the simulator.

Regarding the lack of color matching, the thing you mentioned in your radar but not here is that you'r eon Xcode 8.2.  The correct colorspace should be getting propagated in Xcode 9.  Please try out Xcode 9.2.

Comment: Wait... how are you even using an iPhone X in Xcode 8.2?  I suspect the information in your radar is wrong... ?  Typo?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, in `Xcode 9.2` if I use color literal (in code) and use the color picker to pick a spot on the simulator, it would select the correct colour ?

Comment: @ortwin Thanks.  Looking into it.  BTW, can you run 'xcrun simctl diagnose' when the simulator is booted and attach that to the radar?  There is important information in there (eg: the output of 'xcrun simctl io <device> enumerate') which is helpful for determining what render path is being used on your machine.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia thanks for looking into this. I've uploaded the diagnose log.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Simulator saves images with the "sRGB IEC61966-2.1" profile. When I assign the "Apple RGB" profile to it in Photoshop ("Edit" > "Assign Profile…"), the colors on the screen match the displayed simulator window and any screenshots created on the device (in this case an iPhone X).

Not sure what's wrong exactly but to me this looks like a bug ([rdar://35994235](http://openradar.appspot.com/35994235)).